# Apache Flink scala test maven dependencies errors

Tags: scala, maven, apache-flink, scalatest

I'm trying to generate a jar from a maven project. The project is an Apache Flink (1.3.1) script written in scala (2.11).

My `POM.xml` file is:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>junit</groupId>
  <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
  <version>4.12</version>
  <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.specs2</groupId>
  <artifactId>specs2-core_${scala.compat.version}</artifactId>
  <version>2.4.16</version>
  <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.scalatest</groupId>
  <artifactId>scalatest-maven-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>1.0</version>
  </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
<sourceDirectory>src/main/scala</sourceDirectory>
<testSourceDirectory>src/test/scala</testSourceDirectory>
  <plugins>
    <plugin>
      <!-- see http://davidb.github.com/scala-maven-plugin -->
   <groupId>net.alchim31.maven</groupId>
   <artifactId>scala-maven-plugin</artifactId>
   <version>3.2.0</version>
   <executions>
     <execution>
       <goals>
         <goal>compile</goal>
         <goal>testCompile</goal>
       </goals>
       <configuration>
         <args>
           <arg>-dependencyfile</arg>
           <arg>${project.build.directory}/.scala_dependencies</arg>
         </args>
       </configuration>
     </execution>
   </executions>
 </plugin>
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.scalatest</groupId>
  <artifactId>scalatest-maven-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>1.0</version>
  <configuration>
    <reportsDirectory>${project.build.directory}/surefire-reports</reportsDirectory>
    <junitxml>.</junitxml>
    <filereports>WDF TestSuite.txt</filereports>
  </configuration>
  <executions>
    <execution>
      <id>test</id>
      <goals>
        <goal>test</goal>
      </goals>
    </execution>
  </executions>
</plugin>
</plugins>
</build>
```

I'm working on Eclipse and all the problems and errors I have are related to Scala. What Eclipse notifies me is that type Assertions, type FunSpec, type FunSuite, type JUnitRunner, type ShouldMatchers and other types are not found. In the test folder iI have 3 files, junit.scala (that has no problems), scalatest.scala and specs.scala (both have errors).

I have the same configuration in an other Apache Spark project build with maven and with scala 2.11, and it has no problems.

Any suggestions?

Thanks
LF

Comment: Could you please post the whole `pom.xml` file?

Comment: [link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/cquw46lwqhwk21s/pom.xml?dl=0) @DawidWysakowicz you can find the pom at this url.